# Is it possible to subscribe ROS topic with a Django web-app?

Tags: django, ros

I want to know if it's possible to bind ROS and Django in order to have a web-page which shows the state of a ROS controlled robot.

I just want to have a Django application which subscribe a ROS topic and get the state about the robot, then this application should be able to show these data on a status page.

For now I think that the easiest way is to have a ROS node which write data in files, and the Django app should open and read this data in order to show infos on a page ... But I think it's not very efficient and not bug-proof. Can you help me ?

Comment: Check here: https://github.com/samcrane8/django-ros-turtlesim-server